# array initialisation syntax

Tags: c++, arrays

I've just come across this in code and I don't understand what it's doing, or how it's doing what it's doing

```
pos[iter](1) += 12.0f / 900.0f;
```

does the (1) initialise the array value at position iter to 1, then add (12.0f / 900.0f) to it? I can't believe it is as it's being used in a loop to set the position of debug text, each loop sets the next line below to a high y value (lower point on screen). iter can be 0 or 1 depending on what list the debug text is in.

I would understand if it were a static operation.

Comment: How is `pos` defined?

Comment: You must include the declaration of `pos` in order to understand this line.  It could be a container of function pointers, e.g.

Comment: The important thing here is that it's not some strange syntax you've never seen before. It's just accessing an array and then calling a function.

Comment: Does this code compile? Is it an example from a book? The `(1)` could be a cross-reference to some description, and not meant to be part of the code at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pos[iter](1) += 12.0f / 900.0f;
```

`pos` can be an array, map, or an object of a class with an overloaded `operator[]`. `pos[iter]` returns an object (could be a function pointer, [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) or a class with an overloaded `operator()`) and calls it with a parameter of 1. The function call most likely returns a reference to the returned object as you can mutate its value using `+=`.

So to make it clear, `(1)` is not accessing the 2nd element of anything. It's simply a call to a function or method with that argument. The method returns some object that has a suitable overload of `operator +=` (could be a scalar or an actual class).

Comment: It could also be a pointer to a function pointer... just too many possibilities...